# MVC 3 WebGrid - is inline editing possible?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

Has anyone implemented inline editing using the MVC 3 WebGrid helper?  I've done a lot of searching on the topic, but haven't found much in the way of suggestions.  Also, I'm not in the position of using other 3rd party or open source grids.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's a shame you can't change, I've been using telerik mvc grid for sometime now and it's very easy to use even in complex scenarios.  Well worth considering http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc/grid.aspx

Answer (score 6):

There doesn't seem to be a solution for inline editing with the WebGrid, but given that it's open source and you seem to have a specific requirement I suggest you write some inline editing functionality.  You could then contribute this back to the community and  end up helping other developers with this requirement.

Mike Brind has an [article](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/168/The-WebGrid-Helper-Making-Selections) on creating a popup edit from WebGrid

If you don't have the time or inclination then I strongly suggest either;

- [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.net/demoaspnetmvc.aspx)
- [Telerik MVC Grid](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc/details/Telerik%20Extensions%20for%20ASP.NET%20MVC/grid.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can add inline editing capability to the WebGrid quite easily. I have written an article about it here: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/202/Inline-Editing-With-The-WebGrid